# How can I run statistics on SPSS .sav files in R?

Tags: r, spss

R noob here, I just set up RStudio and imported some .sav SPSS datasets into R Environment. But whenever I try to run tests I get an error saying the file does not exist in the current working directory. I have set the directory to desktop and even tried setting it to the exact folder my file is in and still nothing works. I have spent hours on youtube and I keep getting error after error; I even tried using ChatGPT to give me some basic code. Most of the time when I run a script it is just repeating the syntax in the console + giving me some errors. Please help, I am psychology grad student and I am sick of doing statistics on IBM products

I am hopeless and just about ready to give up on R

Comment: Please show us some code you are trying, how can we know what you are doing wrong without that?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: as the user above said give an example of what you did so we can help but it should be something like this: ```setwd("C:/Users/USER/Documents")
file <- haven::read_sav("TestFile.sav")```

Comment: You may want to try `foreign::read.spss` first if it can read your version; haven can really be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds unrelated to SPSS, so the title is likely misleading.

Find out where you are (with `getwd()`) and what files are in the working directory (with `list.files()`).  When you run [`getwd()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html) and [`list.files()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html), do get the values you expect?

If you're running a nontrivial research project and you have time for ChatGPT, I recommend reading the chapter [Workflow: scripts and projects](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/workflow-scripts.html) for a better long-term .strategy

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the .sav file into R, which will be stored as a data.frame object in R.  Let's see how:

1. For simplicity, set your working directory to be the folder where your .sav file lives

   `setwd("path/to/relevant/folder")`
2. Next, you need access to an R function that can read .sav files.  That function is called `read_sav()` and it lives in the `haven` package.  Assuming you have that package installed (more on that below if you don't), run:

   `mydata <- haven::read_sav("filename.sav")`
3. You now have a data.frame object in R's global environment called `mydata`.  This is the object on which you should operate.  For example, run:

   `summary(mydata)`

---

If you have trouble with step 2, read this:

- You can check whether you have the `haven` package installed by running:

  `find.package("haven")`
- If that returns the path to a folder on your machine, you're good to go.  If it throws an error, then you need to install the package.  To do so, run:

  `install.packages("haven")`
- Now you're ready to read the .sav file into R:

  `mydata <- haven::read_sav("filename.sav")`